# How to display activity feed of my google plus page in my website?

Tags: google-plus

I would like to display the activity feeds of my facebook, twitter, linkedIn, google+ pages in my website. For facebook and twitter, iam getting the feeds by referring their developer website(image attached) . But I dont know how to get the activity feeds from google plus page. Is there any options are available for it ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are tools to help you do this with Google+, but there is no pre-made widget that will do this. You need to combine two components of the Google+ API: the [activities.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list) call and an [embedded post](https://developers.google.com/+/web/embedded-post/).

One very simplistic implementation might look something like this:

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Plus Posts</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
          .post {
            display: block;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>

        <div id="posts"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">

          var plusId = 'profile_id_to_view;
          var apiKey = 'API key from developer console';

          function start(){
            gapi.client.setApiKey( apiKey );
            gapi.client.load('plus','v1', function(){
              console.log('loaded');
              gapi.client.plus.activities.list({
                userId: plusId,
                collection: 'public',
                maxResults: 10
              }).execute(function(resp){
                if( resp && resp.items && resp.items.length > 0 ){
                  for( var co=0; co<resp.items.length; co++ ){
                    $('#posts').append('<div class="post"><div id="posts-'+co+'"></div></div>');
                    var url = resp.items[co].object.url;
                    gapi.post.render('posts-'+co, {url:url});
                  }
                } else {
                  console.log('invalid resp', resp);
                }
              });
            });
          }

          (function(){
            var po = document.createElement( 'script' );
            po.type = 'text/javascript';
            po.async = true;
            po.src = 'https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=start';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' )[0];
            s.parentNode.insertBefore( po, s );
          })();
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

You need to create a project and get your own API key from http://console.developers.google.com/ and provide this and the ID for the posts you wish to follow.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple jquery plugin called [Google+ Feed Widget](https://github.com/kyco/jquery.kyco.googleplusfeed2).

Comment: Have you tried v2 of the plugin? https://github.com/kyco/jquery.kyco.googleplusfeed2
The demo is still working, so maybe it is a configuration https://kyco.github.io/jquery.kyco.googleplusfeed2/

Comment: Didn't know it exists. Actually, I just checked and this link is updated since my previous comment. It has some redirect to Github now. Will give it a try soon